# Find Index in string with Regular Exprerssion starting with some index

Tags: c#

I want to search index of a string \n\n or \n \n or \n \s* \n  search start from some index like

```
 mystring.LastIndexof(regularexpression, mystartindex)
```

and similarly

```
mystring.Indexof(regularexpression, mystartindex)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [this `Regex.Match` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3583dcyh.aspx)

```
public Match Match(
    string input,
    int startat
)
```

E.g.

```
Regex re("\n\s*\n");
var index = re.Match(mystring, mystartindex).Index;
```

Note you can use `Match.NextMatch` to get the next match:

```
Match m = Regex.Match(mystring, re);
while (m.Success) {
   Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
   m = m.NextMatch();
}
```

**Update** Adapted from your own solution:

```
public static class RegexMatchExtensions
{
    public static int LastIndexOf(this MatchCollection matches, int index)
    {
        var match = matches.Cast<Match>().LastOrDefault(m => m.Index <= index);
        return (match == null)? -1 : match.Index;
    }

    public static int IndexOf(this MatchCollection matches, int index)
    {
        var match = matches.Cast<Match>().FirstOrDefault(m => m.Index > index);
        return (match == null)? -1 : match.Index;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
/*private static readonly*/ Regex re = new Regex(@"\n\s*\n",
               RegexOptions.Compiled 
             | RegexOptions.Multiline
             | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);

var doubleLineIndexes = re.Matches(wholeDocumentText);

var first = doubleLineIndexes.IndexOf(73);
var last = doubleLineIndexes.LastIndexOf(73);
```

Comment: if i want to search backward ie lastindexof

Comment: @MuhammadAhsan that's not how Regular expressions work. You'll simply have to iterate till the last match and use it's `.Index`

Comment: @MuhammadAhsan You can write this yourself. If you can't, there is really little use for me to write it for you. [SO] is not a 'write the code for me' site. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: Thanks sehe, I try and let you know

Comment: int LastIndexOf(MatchCollection mathes,int index)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < mathes.Count; i++)
            {
                if (mathes[i].Index > index) return mathes[i-1].Index;
            }
            
            return -1;

        }

        int IndexOf(MatchCollection mathes, int index)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < mathes.Count; i++)
            {
                if (mathes[i].Index > index) return mathes[i].Index;
            }

            return -1;

        }

Comment: sehe i have posted my solution

Answer (score 0):

Regex re = new Regex(@"\n\s*\n");
 MatchCollection DoubleLineIndexes = re.Matches(wholeDocumentText);

int LastIndexOf(MatchCollection mathes,int index)
        {

```
        for (int i = 0; i < mathes.Count; i++)
        {
            if (mathes[i].Index > index) return mathes[i-1].Index;
        }

        return -1;

    }

    int IndexOf(MatchCollection mathes, int index)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < mathes.Count; i++)
        {
            if (mathes[i].Index > index) return mathes[i].Index;
        }

        return -1;

    }
```

Comment: I applaud you writing the mechanics of this :) I have updated my answer with something similar, though (**#1**) phrased as Extension Methods so the usage becomes more convenient (**#2**) fewer bugs (e.g. when the first match was already beyond the start index, LastIndexOf would throw `IndexOutOfRangeException`... (**#3**) much less code, making it clearer what happens (**#4**) regular expression options (esp. `Compiled` and `Multiline`) that could be quite essential for performance and correct operation (depending on the way in which you use it). I hope you like it

Comment: Thank You So much, I love to use your solution.